# Spring CSRF 403 Session expired Internet Explorer 9-11

Tags: java, spring-security, csrf

First of all: disabling CSRF protection is not an option.

To clarify the dependencies

```
compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.5.RELEASE',
        'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:2.1.4.RELEASE',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3',
        'com.google.guava:guava:19.0',
        'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.0.4.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.0.4.RELEASE',
        'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:2.1.2.RELEASE'
```

During a presentation of the milestone of our new app with Internet Explorer 11 suddenly I was not able to login any more. So I was logged in, I manually logged out and since then I'm unable to login. Also after one day and a complete shut down of my computer it's not working any more.

At the same time login is working fine with Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari and also the customer can log in with (drum roll) Internet Explorer.

It is really annoying. So what other IE users will have this problem too?

The login process itself is using AJAX. It's a PUT request.
The Answer in this error case is HTML containing this text `HTTP Status 403 - Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?` and more.

If some one wants to test it: http://int.vr-karriere.de/
The Login is "Anmelden" (German App)

You can use any user and password.
On success you'll see "Der Benutzername oder das Password war falsch." because the server processed the request.
On error you just see "Error during login"

I have no idea why IE behaves that bad for me.

Comment: Cleared your browser cache and tried? I believe you have but just saw shutdown and restart of computer.

Comment: Yes I also did that. IE is set up to do it automatically on quit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in front of the computer.
In a fit of madness I had clicked to block cookies from that server. Stupid!